# Хранение данных приложения в облаке

Tags: android, облако

Есть приложение которое после установки подгружает свои данные на девайс юзера. Сервера под такие нужды естественно нету следовательно как я понимаю выход один - хранение данных в облаке. Может кто подсказать какое облаком подходит для таких нужд (Firebase store не предлогать!) ?

Comment: Тип данных? Статические или динамические? И прочее. Уточните вопрос.

Comment: Статические. Данные - набор изображений, юзер установил приложение, приложение попросила подтвердить загрузку - загрузил все что лежит в облаке и на этом все, причем у приложения есть конфиг который описывает что лежит в облака как где и почему.

Comment: Ну с таким вроде любое облачное хранилище справится (Google Drive, Dropbox, Яндекс Диск ...)